# ExtJS--stop combobox from loading on trigger click

Tags: javascript, extjs

I am using the custom "treecombo" component. Here is the source:

```
/*
Tree combo
Use with 'Ext.data.TreeStore'


If store root note has 'checked' property tree combo becomes multiselect combo (tree store must have records with 'checked' property)


Has event 'itemclick' that can be used to capture click


Options:
selectChildren - if set true and if store isn't multiselect, clicking on an non-leaf node selects all it's children
canSelectFolders - if set true and store isn't multiselect clicking on a folder selects that folder also as a value


Use:


single leaf node selector:
selectChildren: false
canSelectFolders: false
- this will select only leaf nodes and will not allow selecting non-leaf nodes


single node selector (can select leaf and non-leaf nodes)
selectChildren: false
canSelectFolders: true
- this will select single value either leaf or non-leaf


children selector:
selectChildren: true
canSelectFolders: true
- clicking on a node will select it's children and node, clicking on a leaf node will select only that node


This config:
selectChildren: true
canSelectFolders: false
- is invalid, you cannot select children without node


*/
Ext.define('Ext.ux.TreeCombo',
{
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.Picker',
    alias: 'widget.treecombo',
    tree: false,
    constructor: function(config)
    {
        this.addEvents(
        {
            "itemclick" : true
        });


        this.listeners = config.listeners;
        this.callParent(arguments);
    },
    records: [],
    recursiveRecords: [],
    ids: [],
    selectChildren: true,
    canSelectFolders: true,
    multiselect: false,
    displayField: 'text',
    valueField: 'id',
    treeWidth: 300,
    matchFieldWidth: false,
    treeHeight: 400,
    masN: 0,
    recursivePush: function(node, setIds)
    {
        var me = this;


        me.addRecRecord(node);
        if(setIds) me.addIds(node);

        node.eachChild(function(nodesingle)
        {
            if(nodesingle.hasChildNodes() == true)
            {
                me.recursivePush(nodesingle, setIds);
            }
            else
            {
                me.addRecRecord(nodesingle);
                if(setIds) me.addIds(nodesingle);
            }
        });
    },
    recursiveUnPush: function(node)
    {
        var me = this;
        me.removeIds(node);

        node.eachChild(function(nodesingle)
        {
            if(nodesingle.hasChildNodes() == true)
            {
                me.recursiveUnPush(nodesingle);
            }
            else me.removeIds(nodesingle);
        });
    },
    addRecRecord: function(record)
    {
        var me = this;


        for(var i=0,j=me.recursiveRecords.length;i<j;i++)
        {
            var item = me.recursiveRecords[i];
            if(item)
            {
                if(item.getId() == record.getId()) return;
            }
        }
        me.recursiveRecords.push(record);
    },
    afterLoadSetValue: false,
    setValue: function(valueInit)
    {
        if(typeof valueInit == 'undefined') return;

        var me = this,
            tree = this.tree,
            values = (valueInit == '') ? [] : valueInit.split(','),
            valueFin = [];

        inputEl = me.inputEl;


        if(tree.store.isLoading())
        {
            me.afterLoadSetValue = valueInit;
        }


        if(inputEl && me.emptyText && !Ext.isEmpty(values))
        {
            inputEl.removeCls(me.emptyCls);
        }


        if(tree == false) return false;

        var node = tree.getRootNode();
        if(node == null) return false;

        me.recursiveRecords = [];
        me.recursivePush(node, false);

        me.records = [];
        Ext.each(me.recursiveRecords, function(record)
        {
            var id = record.get(me.valueField),
                index = values.indexOf(''+id);

            if(me.multiselect == true) record.set('checked', false);

            if(index != -1)
            {
                valueFin.push(record.get(me.displayField));
                if(me.multiselect == true) record.set('checked', true);
                me.addRecord(record);
            }
        });


        me.value = valueInit;
        me.setRawValue(valueFin.join(', '));

        me.checkChange();
        me.applyEmptyText();
        return me;
    },
    getValue: function() 
    {
        return this.value;
    },
    getSubmitValue: function()
    {
        return this.value;
    },
    checkParentNodes: function(node)
    {
        if(node == null) return;

        var me = this,
            checkedAll = true;


        node.eachChild(function(nodesingle)
        {
            var id = nodesingle.getId(),
                index = me.ids.indexOf(''+id);

            if(index == -1) checkedAll = false;
        });

        if(checkedAll == true)
        {
            me.addIds(node);
            me.checkParentNodes(node.parentNode);
        }
        else
        {
            me.removeIds(node);
            me.checkParentNodes(node.parentNode);
        }
    },
    initComponent: function() 
    {
        var me = this;

        me.tree = Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel',
        {
            alias: 'widget.assetstree',
            hidden: true,
            minHeight: 300,
            rootVisible: (typeof me.rootVisible != 'undefined') ? me.rootVisible : true,
            floating: true,
            useArrows: true,
            width: me.treeWidth,
            autoScroll: true,
            height: me.treeHeight,
            store: me.store,
            listeners:
            {
                load: function(store, records)
                {
                    if(me.afterLoadSetValue != false)
                    {
                        me.setValue(me.afterLoadSetValue);
                    }
                },
                itemclick:  function(view, record, item, index, e, eOpts)
                {
                    me.itemTreeClick(view, record, item, index, e, eOpts, me)
                }
            }
        });

        if(me.tree.getRootNode().get('checked') != null) me.multiselect = true;

        this.createPicker = function()
        {
            var me = this;
            return me.tree;
        };

        this.callParent(arguments);
    },
    addIds: function(record)
    {
        var me = this;

        if(me.ids.indexOf(''+record.getId()) == -1) me.ids.push(''+record.get(me.valueField));
    },
    removeIds: function(record)
    {
        var me = this,
            index = me.ids.indexOf(''+record.getId());

        if(index != -1)
        {
            me.ids.splice(index, 1);
        }
    },
    addRecord: function(record)
    {
        var me = this;


        for(var i=0,j=me.records.length;i<j;i++)
        {
            var item = me.records[i];
            if(item)
            {
                if(item.getId() == record.getId()) return;
            }
        }
        me.records.push(record);
    },
    removeRecord: function(record)
    {
        var me = this;


        for(var i=0,j=me.records.length;i<j;i++)
        {
            var item = me.records[i];
            if(item && item.getId() == record.getId()) delete(me.records[i]);
        }
    },
    itemTreeClick: function(view, record, item, index, e, eOpts, treeCombo)
    {
        var me = treeCombo,
            checked = !record.get('checked');//it is still not checked if will be checked in this event

        if(me.multiselect == true) record.set('checked', checked);//check record

        var node = me.tree.getRootNode().findChild(me.valueField, record.get(me.valueField), true);
        if(node == null) 
        {
            if(me.tree.getRootNode().get(me.valueField) == record.get(me.valueField)) node = me.tree.getRootNode();
            else return false;
        }

        if(me.multiselect == false) me.ids = [];

        //if it can't select folders and it is a folder check existing values and return false
        if(me.canSelectFolders == false && record.get('leaf') == false)
        {
            me.setRecordsValue(view, record, item, index, e, eOpts, treeCombo);
            return false;
        }

        //if record is leaf
        if(record.get('leaf') == true) 
        {
            if(checked == true)
            {
                me.addIds(record);
            }
            else
            {
                me.removeIds(record);
            }
        }
        else //it's a directory
        {           
            me.recursiveRecords = [];
            if(checked == true)
            {
                if(me.multiselect == false)
                {
                    if(me.canSelectFolders == true) me.addIds(record); 
                }
                else
                {
                    if(me.canSelectFolders == true)
                    {
                        me.recursivePush(node, true);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if(me.multiselect == false)
                {
                    if(me.canSelectFolders == true) me.recursiveUnPush(node);
                    else me.removeIds(record);
                }
                else me.recursiveUnPush(node);
            }
        }

        //this will check every parent node that has his all children selected
        if(me.canSelectFolders == true && me.multiselect == true) me.checkParentNodes(node.parentNode);

        me.setRecordsValue(view, record, item, index, e, eOpts, treeCombo);
    },
    fixIds: function()
    {
        var me = this;

        for(var i=0,j=me.ids.length;i<j;i++)
        {
            if(me.ids[i] == 'NaN') me.ids.splice(i, 1);
        }
    },
    setRecordsValue: function(view, record, item, index, e, eOpts, treeCombo)
    {
        var me = treeCombo;

        me.fixIds();

        me.setValue(me.ids.join(','));


        me.fireEvent('itemclick', me, record, item, index, e, eOpts, me.records, me.ids);


        if(me.multiselect == false) me.onTriggerClick();
    }   
});
```

I am using 4 of these custom components, all of which have their own stores which all get loaded when the app is launched. But when the trigger is clicked, it again makes a request to load the store. How can i stop the request from being made on trigger click? The data sets are huge and the store is already loaded so its unnecessarily making another request.

I dont see a trigger click event either otherwise i couldve checked the stores count and perhaps returned false.

thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On your comboboxes add this config to the comboboxes that get loaded early.

```
queryMode: 'local'
```

Comment: thanks for your response. Changing queryMode to "local" fixed problem but now im getting another error the first time trigger is clicked: "me.store.addFilter is not a function". Any ideas?

Comment: From the code above I am not sure where you are assigning store to that treecombo. I see you are doing me.store in your init, but if you go up to the actual definition where it would be refering to me there is no store defined. I would print out me.store and find out what object it is, and then try to go from there. There should be no reason a filter function should be going off. from the looks in your code.